# foreach loop doesn't populate constant variable correctly

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, constants, console.log

I am trying to populate a constant variable with a foreach loop, which it does correctly inside the loop, but it doesn't keep its value when it gets out of the loop. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am fetching data from a firestorm database which I am then trying to save in a constant object
`

```
const customers = {};

customersRef.get()
.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        customers[doc.id] = doc.data();
    });
    console.log(customers);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
});

console.log(customers);
```

`

This gives me the output:
`

```
{
    "correctId": {
        "some": "secretData"
    },
    "correctId": {
        "some": "secretData"
    }
}

{}
```

`

The `console.log()`within the loop gives me the correct data while the same `console.log()` beneath gives me an empty object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't find what I was looking for there

Answer (score -1):

You are not storing the result anywhere. Yo are missing `customers = customersRef.get() ...` at the beginning of your statement.

```
const customers = {};

customers = customersRef.get()
.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        customers[doc.id] = doc.data();
    });
    console.log(customers);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
});

console.log(customers);
```

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks!